Host 3rd party JAR packages in GitHub
I have a large project, comprising several repositories of Maven projects. These depend on a couple of legacy 3rd party JAR files which are not available in Maven central (but they are open source).
Can I create a separate GitHub repository just for hosting these packages, so that my other projects can then download the dependencies from there? For example, I would publish file "tools.jar" with appropriate group and artifact IDs in the new repo "3rd-party-jars".
I tried to upload it with Maven using something like this:
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=./tools.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.0 -DgeneratePom=false -Durl=https://github.com/example-enterprise/3rd-party-jars.git
...but I only get "403 Forbidden" for my efforts.
Is this something that is supposed to work in theory, ie. using GitHub Packages to publish packages which are not built by the same repo?
On the same vein, is it possible to publish artifacts built in different projects (repos) into the same "dependency repo"? That would make cross-dependencies easier between my projects because then I would need to define only one repo for downloads.

https://www.edstem.com/blog/mvn_third_party_jar/ might help

I assume you somehow got these packages yourself. I think the best way is to describe in a README.md of your github project how to get or build them.

You can also, of course, place the necessary libraries in binary artifact repositories:

Publishing to GitHub Packages
Publishing to Maven Central


I also need a place to host those packages because they can't be downloaded from anywhere anymore, and I though GitHub Packages could be used for that since also dependencies built by me are there.

@Sunracer Provided links to official guidelines for publishing packages.

I believe there are different options here. The question is a bit broad, so my answer might be as well.
GH Publish
You probably know this but in GH actions you can set a publish action:
# This workflow will build a package using Maven and then publish it to GitHub packages when a release is created
# For more information see: https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#apache-maven-with-a-settings-path

name: Maven Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        server-id: github # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
        settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      
    - name: Publish to GitHub Packages Apache Maven
      run: mvn deploy -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/settings.xml
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
          

This is a simple maven package release which will basically package according to maven file and publish it to gh. I guess for 3rd party jars you can do some maven configuration.
To fetch from GH:
To install your package, go to the maven settings file. In case you installed maven with homebrew, this should be in the following location /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven//libexec/conf. open the settings.xml file.
In the  section of your settings.xml file paste the following:
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

Replace OWNER and repository with the organisation and repo where the package lives.
In the server settings, paste the following:
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>TOKEN</password>
    </server>

e.g:
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>frankmurphy</username>
      <password>i-should-have-studied-computers-with-maureen</password>
    </server>

To create an access token: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token
Since all the releases should be generated by your maven actions, the token should only have read packages access, if I remember correctly
Then set in your :
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

If you now run mvn install in the project where you need your personal dependency, it should install the dependencies from GitHub.
Note: I had to restart the Intelij using invalidate caches before the dependencies were actually found by the IDE.
Just zip it?
I had to deal with a similar situation recently, where I was also working on a legacy project and had to use 3rd party libraries that were not published anymore.
I ended up zipping the jars. This way I could push them to GH. Then in maven I configured:
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-antrun-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.antrun.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!--install libs not in maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-libs-not-in-maven</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>Installing all libs not in maven</echo>
                                <exec executable="/bin/bash">
                                    <arg value="install-all-libs-not-in-maven-repo.sh" />
                                </exec>
                                <echo>Finished installing all libs not in maven</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
 </plugin>

Assuming that you get a 403 error, I am guessing your configuration is not 100% complete: probably missing the necessary access token or using an expired token.

Thanks for the lengthy answer. Publishing per se is not a problem; I can successfully publish packages from my repos into GitHub Packages. But I also have 3rd party packages which I'm not building myself, but which I would like to host also in GitHub Packages - if only I were able to upload those somehow.
On the second matter, while I'm able to publish (deploy) package A from repo A into repo A Packages, I'm not able to deploy package A from repo A into repo B Packages.
Both of these situations result in 403 which makes me think that maybe GitHub prevents it altogether.

(Just to clarify my previous comment: "deploy package A from repo A into repo B Packages" means that I have repo A where I build the package with Maven, but I try to set the deployment target repo to repo B. I would like to build 4 components from 4 different repos, but deploy their artifacts into a single, fifth repo.)
